# Push Notification Usage limit

Tags: blackberry

I am developing an application to display push notifications.From different website I have learned that there are 2 types of push notifications (essential and plus). I would like to know the usage cost for these 2 push notifications.

Comment: https://developer.blackberry.com/services/push/

Comment: can you please give me some sample applications about push notufucations

Comment: the above link will give you the samples.

Comment: there I didn't see any samples. I mean sample code

Comment: check the "Getting started with the Push Service".below that you will get samples

Comment: I would like to know weather essential push notification is free? And the difference between essential and push notification

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16225/discussion-between-pranavjayadev-and-signare)